# "Proof" that $(2n)!$ is divisible by $2^n 5^{n-3}$ for $n\ge3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, fake-proofs

Please explain, as clearly as possible, what is wrong with the following "proof" by induction that

$\hspace{1.4 in}$$(2n)!$ is divisible by $2^n 5^{n-3}$ for $n\ge3$.

(There clearly must be an error, since the assertion is false for $n=6$.)

**This is true for $n=3$:**

$(2\cdot3)!=5\cdot18\cdot(2^3\cdot5^{3-3})$

**Assume that this is true for $n$:**

$(2n)!=5\cdot{k}\cdot\big(2^{n}\cdot5^{n-3}\big)$

**Prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$(2(n+1))!= (2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)\color{blue}{(2n)!}$

$\hspace{.75 in}=2(n+1)(2n+1)\cdot\color{blue}{5\cdot k\cdot\big(2^n\cdot5^{n-3}\big)}$

$\hspace{.75 in}=(n+1)(2n+1)\cdot k\cdot\color{blue}{\big(2^{n+1}\cdot5^{(n+1)-3}\big)}$

Comment: It being true for $n$ means that $(2n)! = k\cdot(2^n\cdot5^{n-3})$; where do you get the factor of $5$ in that assumption from?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I believe the person who wrote this argument got the  factor of 5 from the base case. If you want to give an answer explaining clearly why that is wrong, I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You assume that $(2n)!$ can be written as $$5k(2^n\cdot5^{n-3})$$

Then you prove that  $(2n+2)!$ can be written as $$k(2^{n+1}\cdot5^{n-2})$$

However, for the induction to hold, one needs to prove that $(2n+2)!$ can be written as $5k(2^{n+1}\cdot5^{n-2})$, because that is what you are assuming in the induction hypothesis.

**Moral:** Always write very clearly down what you are proving with the induction, and check whether that is what you are proving in the base case, hypothesis and induction step.

Comment: Doesn't Steve Stadnicki have a valid question, though, of where the factor of 5 comes from in the factorization of $(2n)!$ in the first place?

Comment: @user84413 I can't read the mind of the proofwriter, but I think he thought that it would work in the base case. So he could assume it also for the hypothesis, and the proving the original statement for the step.

Answer (score 1):

As Steven Stadnicki pointed out, the mistake in this argument is the presence of an extra factor of 5 in the induction hypothesis.

Since we are trying to show that $(2n)!$ is divisible by $2^n5^{n-3}$ for $n\ge3$,

in the induction hypothesis we want to assume that $n$ is an integer with $n\ge3$ such that

$\hspace{.2 in}(2n)!$ is divisible by $2^n5^{n-3}$, which implies that $\color{red}{(2n)!=k(2^n 5^{n-3})}$ for some integer $k$.

---

Notice that the presence of a factor of 5 in the base case does not affect the induction hypothesis, and that the induction step as given only shows that

if $(2n)!$ is divisible by $2^n 5^{n-2}$, then $(2n+2)!$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}5^{n-2}$.